What is this usage of としてなかった。?
家の中心に中庭がある。
白い石が敷き詰められていて、遊ぶには滑るし足が痛かったから、彼にはただの空間であったのだが。
とはいえ居間の縁側や廊下は全て庭に面しており、見ない日は一日としてなかった。
The character is describing his childhood home. He says there is a garden but since he can't play in it for him feels like empty space.
What I'm stumbled, is what is  としてなかった。 here? "見ない日" is day he can see it?

一<counter>として + <negative> means "not a single ...". You can use grammar references like the Dictionaries of Japanese Grammar or A Handbook of Japanese Grammar Patterns to look constructions like this up.

"見ない日" is day he can see it?

Day he doesn't see it (= the garden). -ない means negative ("not"), and there is no "can" here.
「見ない日は　一日として　なかった」on the whole means "there wasn't a single day where he wouldn't catch a glimpse of it" (because all the 居間's corridors and passageways face toward it).
